# RAILS SIDEKIQ SCHEDULER

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, scheduler, sidekiq

I would like to launch the worker after an action and this worker must be launch automatically after every 5 seconds to check a status and when the status is checked, it must be stops. How can I do that? Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you trying to create some jobs and then monitor when the jobs are done?  Please give us more info about what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes i create job after an action like an registration or payment. The  Job must be run each 5 seconds to check some status. If status is true, job must be stop. Are you understand what i want?

Comment: No, I don't.  Give me more specific info about this business logic.  What is the status check?  What is the job doing?

Comment: Ok, this  is the scenario:  user upload a file after upload i send the file to another service to verify if it's  OK or KO. During verification, i create a job to check if service has finished to verified it.  If  response's service is  OK, job must be stop...

Comment: Job runs  after each 5 seconds

Comment: Somebody can help me please please??

Comment: Use `perform_in(N.seconds, ...)` to schedule a job to check in N seconds.  Check every N seconds for a few minutes.

Comment: Oh thank you. But how can i stop job  when file will be verified (example above)

Comment: Just don't schedule another job.  If the status is false, the job will schedule another job to run in N seconds.  If the status is true or you've performed more than X checks, just return and don't schedule anything.